# c++ copy constructor between different templates

Tags: c++, templates, copy

I have a template class A. What I want to do is to write a copy constructor between A with template T1 and A with template T2. How do I solve this? Here is some example code from the struct header:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    A(const A<T>& other); // copy from same type T
    template <typename T2>
    A(const A<T2>& other); // copy from different type T2
}
```

How would I go about to implement this in a .cpp file?

EDIT: What I really meant was: "How would I go about to implement this outside the class definition?" (a syntax problem)

Comment: templates go in header files

Comment: of course! What I meant was "How would I go about to implement this outside the class definition?"

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for defining a template member function of a template class is not immediately obvious. You need to have two template parameter lists; one for the class and one for the function:

```
template <typename T>  //class template parameters
template <typename T2> //function template parameters
A<T>::A (const A<T2>& other) {
    //...
}
```

Note that templates need to be implemented in the header file, so you can't put this in the `.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define template function in .cpp file. But in header, outside of class definition you can just

```
template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
A<T>::A(const A<T2&>& other)
{
   // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make that other constructor a template itself:

```
template< class T > class A
{
public:
    A()
    {

    }

    A(const A<T> & other)
    {
        cout << "T" << endl;
    }

    template<class T1> A(const A<T1> & other)
    {
        cout << "T1" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a1;
    A<int> a2 = a1; // prints "T"
    A<double> a3 = a1; // prints "T1"
    return 0;
}
```